# jsf2 silent fail on commandButton/link

Tags: jsf-2, el, mojarra

This question is not about any single piece of code, as I have several pages with problems.  I am using Jboss AS 7.1.1 with jsf 2.1, but have tried Wildfly as well.

I have several pages I am moving from jsf 1 with Seam 3 to jsf2/CDI.  On some of these pages h:commandButtons will never call the action method, or display any error message.  If I set the logging to finest, I can see that JSF is recieving a post, but jumps right from Restore View to Render Response.  My question is, how can I trouble shoot this?  Is there any way to have JSF2 not fail silently?

Thanks,
Mason

Comment: Apparently it failed to restore the expected view. Check the session and the view state parameter. I also recommend to create a separate and brand new Hello World JSF2 project and check how that works out for you and then add artifacts of the old project one by one until it breaks. Perhaps there's a JSF 1.x specific artifact left over which should be upgraded/modified to be JSF 2.x compatible.

Comment: Thanks BalusC.  Unfortunately this is a fairly massive project, and of the hundreds of pages that I have ported over only a couple are having problems I can't seem to resolve.  Those pages are very large, and would take weeks to move into a new Hello World JSF2 project.  I am guessing you are right that there are JSF1.x specific artifacts, I just wish I could enable some sort of JSF debugging or useful error messages to find out what without having to spend days on trial and error.